# ITransportHeartbeat.GetConnections() gets me disconnected connections

Tags: signalr

In SignalR, the implementation of `ITransportHeartbeat.GetConnections()` should get me a list of connections being tracked. In one of my cases, I was always getting a web socket connection which didn't exist anymore.

Here is how I retrieve the default `ITransportHeartbeat` instance:

```
SignalRAutofac.Initialize();
IDependencyResolver resolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver;
ITransportHeartbeat heartbeat = resolver.Resolve<ITransportHeartbeat>();
```

I am assuming SignalR is sending heartbeat to the tracked connection in a specific interval. Is this the case? If yes, I didn't see that dead connection being dropped for 5 minutes from the list. Is this usual? is that dead connection supposed to live throughout the lifetime of the AppDomain?

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen 1.1.2 on .NET 4.5. Hosting it on ASP.NET.

Comment: @tugberk Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @tugberk Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @tugberk Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @ajbeaven @Raghav @SherleyDev I had to check what I have done. I apparently started checking `IsAlive` property on the connection and ignore the not alive ones.

Comment: @tugberk Hmm... already doing that. Thanks for the update though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the IsAlive property on the retrieved connections.